# Xcode Archive Validation Errors - Xcode 9 and Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

When I try to upload the app to the app store using Xcode archive, following validation errors are coming up:

> iTunes Store Operation Failed Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
>   'Dvp.app/Frameworks/AlamofireSwiftyJSON.framework' contains disallowed
>   file 'Frameworks'.
>
> iTunes Store Operation Failed Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
>   'Dvp.app/Frameworks/AlamofireSwiftyJSON.framework' contains disallowed
>   nested bundles.
>
> iTunes Store Operation Failed CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is
>   more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value
>   'com.swiftyjson.SwiftyJSON' under the iOS application 'Dvp.app'.
>
> iTunes Store Operation Failed CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is
>   more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value
>   'org.alamofire.Alamofire' under the iOS application 'Dvp.app'.

I have referred these frameworks by drag and dropping them to the my project. I didn't use cocoapod or swift package manager to refer third party frameworks to the project.

Any idea how can I get rid of these validation issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case these validation errors occurred because of the *AlamofireSwiftyJSON* framework. Errors are as follows:

> iTunes Store Operation Failed Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
>   'Dvp.app/Frameworks/AlamofireSwiftyJSON.framework' contains disallowed
>   file 'Frameworks'.
>
> iTunes Store Operation Failed Invalid Bundle. The bundle at
>   'Dvp.app/Frameworks/AlamofireSwiftyJSON.framework' contains disallowed
>   nested bundles.

To remove the above mentioned errors I just selected the *AlamofireSwiftyJSON* target and add a "Run Script" in the "Build Phase" tab.

Refer the following image:

[image]

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks" ]]; then
rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```

This fixed the above mentioned validation errors and the following validation errors as well:

> iTunes Store Operation Failed CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is
>   more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value
>   'com.swiftyjson.SwiftyJSON' under the iOS application 'Dvp.app'.
>
> iTunes Store Operation Failed CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is
>   more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value
>   'org.alamofire.Alamofire' under the iOS application 'Dvp.app'.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After you archive the app , generate the ipa with AppStore selection , and upload it with Application Loader

Answer (score 0):

For me the key to solve this, in addition to `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO`, also setting `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT=NO` in build settings for all targets except the main app target. Had to clear out derived data, but after that all was well.

[image]

Comment: You mean I have to set these keys for all the third party libraries right? Do I need to do these only for iOS target?

Comment: I tried these 2 settings and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you do that for IOS target?

Comment: Yes I did for the iOS target.

Comment: Anything else I have to think about. This alamofire has 4 targets. ex: macOS, tvOS and watchOS. Do I need to do anything about them?

Comment: Do the same steps for all your third party libraries or
 Open the (Your App).xcodeproj file (this is the first file on the project navigator pane).Switch to the target for your app extension (on the top left of the middle pane).Go to the Build Phases tab.Click the X after "Embed Pod Frameworks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166414/discussion-between-oshadha-and-md-rashed-pervez).

Comment: I tried removing embeded frameworks and it crashes when I run it against my iPhone
gives me an error called couldn't load dynamic lib.

Comment: Anything else that I have to think about?